# Are there any metrics on how much more resource-intensive KDE is versus Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, performance, gnome, kde

I've just started looking at KDE and it's obviously a much slicker interface to Ubuntu than Gnome.

Any information available on how much additional hardware resources it takes to generate all that visual slickness?

I'm running Ubuntu on a 4 year old laptop with no dedicated graphics card (just the Intel Core Duo single-core graphics chip - whatever that's called). I'm concerned it might not be up to the task.

Comment: What makes you say that KDE is "slicker"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around 2 years old, but some very useful information here: [Desktop Memory Usage](http://ktown.kde.org/~seli/memory/desktop_benchmark.html). I found this page when comparing XFCE and GNOME a long time ago, lots of useful information.

Comment: Whoa. That's surprising. The results go completely against my intuition that KDE would be more resource-intensive than Gnome because it seems more graphics-heavy. It's just one test I guess, but still, quite surprising. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What is described there is a previous version of KDE - the page is about 2 years old, as you noticed. The current KDE is TOTALLY changed with respect to that one and I'm quite certain that those conclusions no longer apply.